# Calling a razor page from an aspx page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-4.0

We have  a big project created with `webforms`(`asp.net 4.0`),and have masterpage,menus and so on,
and we have to make a new project(we choosed `MVC`,for separation concerns) but it has to be integrated in this webform portal.I added in the solution of the webforms application a new `mvc` project,now:
how can i call a page of the `MVC` project(created with `razor`,usually the index page) from the `aspx` page(the main page which has a masterpage,or from a simple content page)?
in the webforms application we have a vertical menu,and we should be able to call from such a menu,the main razor page from the mvc project,in order to start working with the new application,from the old webforms app,just like a portal.
If there are several possibilities  to call a razor page from an aspx page,which are they?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

read this for more info [Razor and Asp.net webforms in Mixed Mode](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)

from soctt hansleman Post

> Html.RenderPartial or Html.RenderAction is an opportunity to
>   move between view engines. As Eilon Lipton says, the idea of a partial
>   view or controller action is a first-class concept in ASP.NET MVC, but
>   master pages are implementation details of the specific view engines.
>
> You can put shared content in Partials then call them from wherever.
>   For example, from Eilon's suggestion, let's say you had these three
>   WebForms partial views

Comment: i wonder also,is possible to put a razor page inside a master-page created with aspx engine or each engine reders its own kind of master-page(layout) ?!

Comment: i found out that the mvc pages should be called in a IFrame,at least the other pages,created in aspx are called dinamically with src property set to the name of aspx page.it is possible to call a simple razor page,in a iframe ?